# filtering values from bytearray

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, tuples

I have a list of bytearrays, some of the items are:

```
bytearray(b'0.266 : 2\x00\xc9\n\xa0\x01\x00\x00p\x99\xcd\x88')
bytearray(b'0.264 : 3\x00\xc9\n\xa0\x01\x00\x000.12')
bytearray(b'0.263 : 4\x00\xdc\n\xa0\x01\x00\x000.25')
bytearray(b'0.255 : 5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00')
bytearray(b'0.266 : 6\x00\xce\n\xa0\x01\x00\x000.13')
bytearray(b'0.263 : 7\x00\xd6\n\xa0\x01\x00\x00\xe0\x98]\n')
bytearray(b'0.273 : 8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x9d]\n')
bytearray(b'0.269 : 9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x9d]\n')
bytearray(b'0.272 : 10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x9f]\n')
bytearray(b'0.275 : 11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x9d]\n')
bytearray(b'0.272 : 12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd0\x9e]\n')
bytearray(b'0.274 : 13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000.26')
bytearray(b'0.278 : 14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x9d]\n')
bytearray(b'0.272 : 15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x9f]\n')
bytearray(b'0.27 : 16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x9d]\n')
bytearray(b'0.276 : 17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00')
bytearray(b'0.272 : 18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\x9f]\n')
bytearray(b'0.277 : 19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Pz\xb1\n')
```

I want to filter out the starting values  i.e. `0.277 : 19`, ideally in the form of a tuple. I tried decoding usign `b.decode()` but receive the followin error:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf0 in position 8: invalid continuation byte

an important thing to note is that sometimes the floats have 2 decimal places but at max they have 3. Is there a simple way to get that information out in the form of a tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
arrays = [
    bytearray(b'0.266 : 2\x00\xc9\n\xa0\x01\x00\x00p\x99\xcd\x88'),
    bytearray(b'0.264 : 3\x00\xc9\n\xa0\x01\x00\x000.12'),
    bytearray(b'0.263 : 4\x00\xdc\n\xa0\x01\x00\x000.25'),
    bytearray(b'0.255 : 5\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'),
    bytearray(b'0.266 : 6\x00\xce\n\xa0\x01\x00\x000.13'),
    bytearray(b'0.263 : 7\x00\xd6\n\xa0\x01\x00\x00\xe0\x98]\n'),
    bytearray(b'0.273 : 8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xa0\x9d]\n'),
    bytearray(b'0.269 : 9\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x9d]\n'),
    bytearray(b'0.272 : 10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x9f]\n'),
    bytearray(b'0.275 : 11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x9d]\n'),
    bytearray(b'0.272 : 12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd0\x9e]\n'),
    bytearray(b'0.274 : 13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000.26'),
    bytearray(b'0.278 : 14\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x9d]\n'),
    bytearray(b'0.272 : 15\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x000\x9f]\n'),
    bytearray(b'0.27 : 16\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00 \x9d]\n'),
    bytearray(b'0.276 : 17\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00'),
    bytearray(b'0.272 : 18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`\x9f]\n'),
    bytearray(b'0.277 : 19\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00Pz\xb1\n'),
]

print(len(arrays))  # 18

pattern_to_exclude = b'0.277 : 19'
filtered_arrays = list(filter(lambda bytes: bytes[0:len(pattern_to_exclude)] != pattern_to_exclude, arrays))

print(len(filtered_arrays))  # 17
print(filtered_arrays[-1][0:10])  # bytearray(b'0.272 : 18')
```

Just checking that the start of the bytearray does not match the pattern. I used [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) but the same could be done with a regular loop.
The final print is there to show that the last bytearray is no longer present, as it was the only one matching the pattern.